# Create several empty lists and assign them to different variables

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want to create as many empty lists as there are integers in `lst` (a list of integers) and add those integers in `lst` to the end of each variable assigned to each empty list:

```
def create_3C_object_lists( lst ):
        """ creates all necessary lists """
        for i in range(len(lst)):
                exec("globals()['_3C_%d'] = []" % (lst[i]))
                print(type(_3C_%d)) % (lst[i])
```

What I hope to get:

```
_3C_(integer at index 0 in lst)
_3C_(integer at index 1 in lst)
...
```

and so on. Is there a better way of doing this? Perhaps without "exec" ?

Comment: You are better off making a list than making a bunch of variables with similar names.

Comment: I need a bunch of lists though, for later reference in my program. I'm appending things to these lists from a much larger list based on the numbers at the end so later I can create combinations via what is in these lists. There are a lot of items and it would be simpler for me to visualize if I could simply categorize them via these lists.

Comment: You can make a list of lists.

Comment: Ive thought of that, but geez...that'd be one looong list of lists :(

Answer (score 2):

Just create a dictionary:

```
_3C_ = {i: [] for i in lst}
# Use it like this:
_3C_[17].append(...)
```

If for some reason you really need a variable, you can do it without `exec` like this:

```
globals()['_3C_{}'.format(your_integer)] = []
```